# Showing 'tick marks' with HTML range sliders

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am trying to show 'ticks' with HTML range sliders. Like this:
[image: range with ticks]

While the HTML range directive allows for ticks with "step" and "datalist", Safari does not honor it while Chrome does. I am building an ionic/Angular app, so this means it does not work for iOS devices.

There are some 3rd party sliders like angular-awesome-slider that do support a form of ticks, but they have other issues which make them less usable for my need.

So my requirement is this: Given an HTML range slider, how do I go about adding an overlay on top that displays "|" marks at specific places on top of the slider?
(Note that the positioning of the "|" needs to take into account the display width of the slider)

I've set up a codepen here:

> http://codepen.io/pliablepixels/pen/EjdpVB?editors=101

(SO insists if I insert a codepen link, I need to also insert code, so here is the code for the input)

```
<input type=range ng-model="myRange" min=0 max=20 step = 1 list="vals">

    <datalist id="vals">
      <option>2</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>8</option>
   </data-list>
```

with an input range. As you see it shows ticks on Chrome but not on Safari. Can someone be so kind as to help me get started with my objective?

Answer (score 0):

This is way late :-) But are you sure (I don't have an installed Safari to check) that it wouldn't help if  your `<datalist id="vals">` tag matched your `</data-list>` tag?

I'm frankly surprised that it works for Chrome! Though it definitely breaks if you change the opening tag to `<data-list>`